# ZodError in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i am currently working on a discord bot project and keep running into a problem :
when i try to register a new command, IF I try tu use the .addUserOption method, I get a ZodError (see below)(Zod being a module used by the SlashCommandBuilder ?). I can and have registered simple commands without trouble, but i keep getting the zodError. I have uninstalled and reinstalled discord.js to be sure but to no avail. I believe the error does not come from my code because i triple checked it from the discord.js documentation.

My error :

```
ZodError: [
  {
    "validation": "regex",
    "code": "invalid_string",
    "message": "Invalid",
    "path": []
  }
],
  format: [Function (anonymous)],
  addIssue: [Function (anonymous)],
  addIssues: [Function (anonymous)],
  flatten: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

My code :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('Title')
        .setDescription('Bottom text')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('Subtitle')
            .setDescription('Lorem Ipsum')
            .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Not defined yet');
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you include your package.json

Comment: `{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "mainBot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": ""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "HEELZacky",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.11.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.2.0-canary.0",
    "@r6stats/node": "^4.0.0-alpha3",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.26.1",
    "discord.js": "^13.5.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "trueskill": "0.0.2"
  }
  }
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zod is a part of the discord.js builders. This is because the command names are uppercase. Make both the command name and option name lowercase

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('title')
        .setDescription('Bottom text')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName('subtitle')
            .setDescription('Lorem Ipsum')
            .setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Not defined yet');
    },
}
```

Comment: Nice one :) That error message is far from perfect though. I wish they could add a custom one at least [for the regex](https://github.com/discordjs/builders/blob/main/src/interactions/slashCommands/Assertions.ts#L23).

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros in the discord.js official discord server, they were talking about how they were going to make more specific errors.